# How can I create a wait wheel after a button click until a pdf file is downloaded using C# and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

wait wheel after a button click until a pdf file is downloaded

hello, I'm trying to write a c# program that creates a wait wheel after a button click until a pdf file is downloaded. I'm trying to do this without using a timer. Do you have any idea ?